# Как переопределить направление открытия тултипа | IOS | WebView

Tags: ios, webview

IOS | WKWebView

Есть на странице инпут на contenteditable. Проблема в том, что по какой-то причине при выделении текста тултип открывается вниз, что перекрывает кнопки. Можно как-то принудительно открывать его только вверх? Или можете подсказать, как он ориентируется в пространстве?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]